# How to use Http Request Sampler to click on a checkbox

Tags: css, xpath, jmeter

I have an HTML rendered page, in which I need to access `<tr class="width-full" selected>` see full picture below:
[image]

so when the checkbox is selected we have:

```
<tr class="width-full" selected>
```

and when not selected, its:

```
<tr class="width-full">
```

How can I use an HTTP sampler to click on the checkbox, perhaps using XPath or CSSSelector?
not sure how I would traverse from <input to <tr and force "selected"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> **JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level**. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

so JMeter doesn't actually "click" anything.

So if "clicking" triggers a [HTTP request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) (you can check it using "Network" tab of your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools)) - you can simulate the same request using JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler)

If the "click" doesn't trigger the network request - you won't be able to do this using JMeter (unless you want to kick off a real browser via [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered) which provides JMeter integration with [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) browser automation framework)

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T I followed your advice and ended up finding an ID in the URL which was the trigger to actually "certify" which is the functionality I wanted to achieve. For this, we need intimate knowledge of the web application. Thanks